# How to assign object property to a textbox in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

In my project I am using Angular 2 and I have coded like:

```js
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/json')
.map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(data =>{ this.result = data });
```

and the Object(this.result) is loaded into the smart table. It works perfect but I want to display the Name from result in a textbox above the smart table. I coded like:

```html
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="result.Name">
    <br/><ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source"></ng2-smart-table>
```

But this is not working, is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a model variable

name : String;

and then

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/json')
.map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(data =>{ 
   this.result = data;
   this.name = data[0].name; //access the index you need     
 });
```

and use it as,

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name ">
```